# Ambiguous Overload in cin>> operator

Tags: c++, operators, iostream

For some reason, I get an error:

> ambiguous operator for operator 'operator>>' in 'std::cin>>C1'.

#### Declaration: ComplexNumber.h

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, const ComplexNumber & n);
istream & operator>>(istream & in, ComplexNumber & n);
```

#### Implementation: ComplexNumber.cpp

```
ostream& operator << (ostream & out, const ComplexNumber & n)
{
    n.print(out);
    return out;
}

istream& operator >> (istream & in, ComplexNumber & n)
{
    char c1[10];
    cout<<("Enter complex number: ");
    in>>c1;
    double a,b;
    a=c1[0]-'0';
    b=c1[2]-'0';
    ComplexNumber answer(a,b);
    n=answer;
    return in;
}
```

#### main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    ComplexNumber C1();
    cin>>C1;
    return 0;
}
```

#### compiler error

```
candidates are: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type&  std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT,  _Traits>::__istream_type& (*)(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>
```

Comment: The compiler lists _candidates_ underneath where it tells you "ambiguous overload". Tell us what they are.

Comment: 'candidates are: std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::operator>>(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type& (*)(std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::__istream_type&)) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>'

Answer (score 8):

```
ComplexNumber C1();
```

This doesn't do what you think it does.

A declaration of an object with automatic storage duration generally takes one of the following two forms:

```
Type name(constructor-arguments); // (1)
Type name;                        // (2)
```

Note that the second form does **not** have an empty set of parentheses (`()`).

That's because one of C++'s quirks is that the following declares a function called `name` that returns an object of type `Type`:

```
Type name();                      // (3)
```

Now, you didn't tell us what the candidate overloads were as listed by your compiler's diagnostic output, but evidently your declared function `name` can be converted to more than one target type, thus causing an "ambiguous overload" error; regardless, *none* of the candidates are actually what you meant.

This "problem" is known as the "[Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)".

Instead, write:

```
int main() {
   ComplexNumber C1;
   cin >> C1;
}
```

I also recommend:

- Indenting your code to make it legible;
- Using `std::string` rather than C-style strings.

Comment: This makes sense! Thanks again for pointing out the issues and editing my post. Will keep formatting in mind.

Answer (score 2):

```
ComplexNumber C1();
```

declares a function `C1()` which takes no parameters and returns a `ComplexNumber`.

This is called as the **Most Vexing Parse** in C++.

Answer (score 2):

This statement:

```
ComplexNumber C1();
```

doesn't create an instance of a `ComplexNumber`.  Instead, it declares a function called `C1` that takes no arguments and returns a `ComplexNumber`.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse.